# whats replace of ThreadAbortException for winRT

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

I am converting .Net code to winRT. I searched but did not find replace of ThreadAbortException that I may write for winRT. Please tell me about this or about some general thread exception.

Thanks

Comment: There is not Thread.Abort() in WinRT.  So of course no ThreadAbortException either.  Do avoid using types that don't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no thread abort in winRT. so, you don't need to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most similar error you can use is `OperationCanceledException`. This error is thrown by WinRT asynchronous operations when they are aborted and it is supported in all WinRT projections. For more information, take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/hh699896.aspx